# How to get the right content to be displayed with buttons? (Vue/vuetify)

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use v-if and v-show to display the contents of two different pages. If you click on button A, the table for page A is displayed, and if you click on button B, the table for page B is displayed. But with the code I have now, both pages are displayed when clicking on button B. How can I get the right page depending on the button that is clicked? I'm thinking of using v-if/else but I'm not sure how.

My code:

```
<template>
<v-main>
    <v-row align="center" justify="space-around">
<v-col class="text-center" cols="10" sm="7">
       <v-btn v-on:click="first= !first">View first table</v-btn>
       <p v-show="first"><FirstTable/></p>
       <v-btn v-on:click="second= !second">View second table</v-btn>
       <p v-show="second"><SecondTable/></p>
</v-col>

</v-row>
</v-main>

</template>


  <script>
  import FirstTable from '@/pages/main-page/FirstTable'
  import SecondTable from '@/pages/main-page/SecondTable'
  export default {
  name: 'MainPage',
  components: {
      FirstTable,
      SecondTable

  },
  data() {
    return {
        first: false,
        second: false
    }
  },

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are not setting first to false again. anyway heres a way of doing it.

```
<template>
<v-main>
    <v-row align="center" justify="space-around">
    <v-col class="text-center" cols="10" sm="7">
       <v-btn @click="toggleTable('first')">View first table</v-btn>
       <FirstTable v-if="activeTable === 'first'"/>
       <v-btn @click="toggleTable('second')">View second table</v-btn>
       <SecondTable v-if="activeTable === 'second'"/>
</v-col>

</v-row>
</v-main>

</template>


  <script>
  import FirstTable from '@/pages/main-page/FirstTable'
  import SecondTable from '@/pages/main-page/SecondTable'
  export default {
  name: 'MainPage',
  components: {
      FirstTable,
      SecondTable
  },
  data() {
    return {
        activeTable: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
      toggleTable(val) {
          this.activeTable = val;
      }
  },
};
```

Comment: do you know how I can make the second button stay in place when I click on the first button? Right now if I click on the first button, the second button appears in the bottom of the page

Comment: move it around.